# How to add cancel button to ErrorDialog of GooglePlayServicesUtil?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using checking of google play services availability and want to create ErrorDialog with cancel button (with custom cancelClickListener). Are there any ways to achieve it?

public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(){

```
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }       
    else  {         
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);           
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    ...
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the GooglePlayServicesUtil method returns a Dialog and not an AlertDialog.

If you want this sort of custom behaviour, you need to implement your own AlertDialog (or something similar) which handles starting an activity for result, displaying a proper error message for a given status code, etc. It would be quite a hassle to achieve - if you want cancellation just use `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` and don't set the `OnKeyListener`.

Comment: Thanks, just hoped there is simple way.